# Invalid use of null

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I hope this is my last problem I have with this database. I wrote a code: All is it is averaging a group of inputs.

```
Public Sub CalcOverallRating()
Dim li_CalcValue As Integer

If IsNull((Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP1]!CBX_PP1.Value) Or _
           IsNull(Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP2]!CBX_PP2.Value) Or _
           IsNull(Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP3]!CBX_PP3.Value) Or _
           IsNull(Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP4]!CBX_PP4.Value) Or _
           IsNull(Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP5]!CBX_PP5.Value) Or _
           IsNull(Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP6]!CBX_PP6.Value) Or _
           IsNull(Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP7]!CBX_PP7.Value)) Then
    'Don't calculate if any values are null
Else
    li_CalcValue = (Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP1]!CBX_PP1.Value + _
                    Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP2]!CBX_PP2.Value + _
                    Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP3]!CBX_PP3.Value + _
                    Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP4]!CBX_PP4.Value + _
                    Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP5]!CBX_PP5.Value + _
                    Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP6]!CBX_PP6.Value + _
                    Forms![FRM_CSR]![PP7]!CBX_PP7.Value) / 7
    Forms![FRM_CSR].Text270.Value = li_CalcValue
    Forms![FRM_CSR].[Overall CSR].Value = li_CalcValue
End If

End Sub
```

Also with this I have a Call CalcOverallRating in each of the forms names FRM_PP1 through FRM_PP7.

When use the combobox it comes up with the error of Invalid use of Null.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included all of your conditions in the first `IsNull()` function. These should be separated conditions:

```
If IsNull(something) Or IsNull(somethingElse) ... Then
```

remove the opening and closing parentheses.

Comment: Thank you sir. I wish I could take you out to eat or something haha. I am still working on the scroll bar issue but I think I should be able to get it.